# Appcelerator Studio - All xml views scrambled

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am using appcelerator studio App Designer view to layout my application view, but when I imported it into another system it all looks scrambled, what can I do to resolve this. I am new to appcelerator studio development. Below is the screen shot for your reference. Any pointers will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: did you take all related tss/xml/js with the view? And are you sure everything is copied over?

Comment: Yes Everything is copied and have taken all tss xml and js.

Comment: can you show us the XML and TSS file?